# Esrally giving multiple search queries in the same track.json

Tags: elasticsearch

Could we give multiple search queries in the same track.json
I want to give 2 queries which given below/ So I added it in several places in different ways to organize it . However, when I validate the .json , I get operation key is duplicated or json is invalid. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes refer https://esrally.readthedocs.io/en/stable/track.html#schedule
Also the https://discuss.elastic.co/t/esrally-giving-multiple-search-queries-in-the-same-track-json/279184/2

Solution will be

```
{
  "version": 2,
  "description": "Tutorial benchmark for Rally Search",
  "indices": [
    {
      "name": "customrecords",
      "types": [
        "docs"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "schedule": [
    {
      "operation": {
        "operation-type": "cluster-health",
        "request-params": {
          "wait_for_status": "green"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "operation": {
        "name": "term-search",
        "operation-type": "search",
        "body": {
          "query": {
            "term": {
              "body": "Lago"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "clients": 4,
      "warmup-iterations": 1000,
      "iterations": 6000,
      "target-throughput": 100
    },
    {
      "operation": {
        "name": "match-all-query",
        "operation-type": "search",
        "body": {
          "query": {
            "match_all": {}
          }
        }
      },
      "clients": 4,
      "warmup-iterations": 1000,
      "iterations": 6000,
      "target-throughput": 100
    }
  ]
}
```